# Merge function of mergesort removing the largest alphabetically valued entry struct

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, memory, allocation

The mergesort functions correctly sort until the last iteration, in which the largest alphabetical value is removed completely from the finished array. I'm new to C, and am struggling with this one because the mergesort **works perfectly** with the OCCURRENCES attribute of the ENTRY struct but not with the char array WORDS when using strcmp.. it should work the same, here's the code for the struct and for the merge and sort functions:

here is a sample of my output: The file contains
 "Hello world how how are you doing"

```
| hello                | 1          |
| world                | 1          |
| how                  | 2          |
| are                  | 1          |
| you                  | 1          |
| doing                | 1          |
+-----------------------------------+

+_____________________________+
| Word          | Occurrences |
+-----------------------------+
| how          | 2            |
| doing        | 1            |
| you          | 1            |
| are          | 1            |
| world        | 1            |
| hello        | 1            |
+-----------------------------+

+___________________________________+
| Word           | Occurrences      |
+-----------------------------------+
| are                  | 1          |
| doing                | 1          |
| hello                | 1          |
| how                  | 2          |
| world                | 1          |
+-----------------------------------+
zoe@zoe-VirtualBox:~/Analysis$ ^C
```

Comment: I think you have a copy paste error: `while(l <= high) b[i++] = a[l++];` Should be `while(m <= high) b[i++] = a[m++];`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, if i change the l to m it 
gives me a segmentation error. The sorting method works perfectly for numerical sorting, it's giving me a faulty output for the case where mode != TRUE

Comment: No. It doesn't "work perfectly". It works on the test cases you tried. Try some other test cases. :)

Comment: How are you calling `sort`?

Comment: Sort is called in main, i added the source code, thanks again for taking a look. I really am unfamiliar with C. I've mainly worked in java, which does all the hard work for you lol

Comment: Hard to tell. You might be calling sort with one value too much. Your sort expects to be called with an *inclusive* range; ie: values `low=0` and `high=size-1`. You are calling with `high=size` which *might* be 1 more than you want. I can't tell though because `size` is computed from another function. If you add some prints, you'll be able to debug your out of bounds issue.

Comment: I've been using ddd debugger.  Still no clear resolution. I'm just gonna call it a day. Thanks again for taking the time to look through! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a copy/paste error in your `merge` function. Instead of:

```
while(l <= high) b[i++] = a[l++];
```

You want:

```
while(m <= high) b[i++] = a[m++];
```

After this your sorting code works fine.

Here is some test code.  I called it with:

```
./sortTest hello world hello rabbit dog fox hen worm world 01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789 01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789 ant
```

And the output was returned as:

```
Results ... 
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123 2
ant 1
dog 1
fox 1
hello 2
hen 1
rabbit 1
world 2
worm 1
```

Here is the test code:

```
ENTRY *find_dup(ENTRY* entries, const char *str, int N)
{
    ENTRY *dup = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (strncmp(entries[i].WORD, str, sizeof(entries[i].WORD)-1) == 0)
        {
            dup = entries + i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return dup;
}

void print_entries(const ENTRY* entries, int N)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s %d\n", entries[i].WORD, entries[i].OCCURRENCES);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    int i, N=0;
    ENTRY *entries = malloc((argc-1)*sizeof(*entries));
    ENTRY *scratch = malloc((argc-1)*sizeof(*entries));
    for(i=1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        ENTRY *dup = find_dup(entries, argv[i], N);
        if (dup == NULL)
        {
            strncpy(entries[N].WORD, argv[i], sizeof(entries[N].WORD));
            entries[N].WORD[sizeof(entries[N].WORD)-1] = 0;
            entries[N].OCCURRENCES = 1;
            ++N;
        }
        else
        {
            ++dup->OCCURRENCES;
        }
    }

    sort(entries, scratch, 0, N-1, 0);

    fprintf(stdout, "Results ... \n");
    print_entries(entries, N);    

    free(entries);
    free(scratch);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: L is incrementing to m and m to high, so by the time we get to the second while, m would increment past high causing a segmentation fault

Comment: No. `l` is incrementing to `mid` and `m` is incrementing to `high`. You can see this from your for loop that performs the comparisons. `for(i; l <= mid && m <= high; i++)`. How are you calling `sort`?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, so the merge and sort functions are operating correctly, it must be an issue with the way I allocated memory or the size return. I will try and correct on my end, I'll update momentarily.

Comment: Okay thank you, I got it to work, It was attempting to continue to sort well after it was already sorted, truncating words on my end. THANKS A TON! I can finally relax :D